# Running a sequence in batches using asSequence()?

Tags: list, kotlin, sequence

I have a function:

```
private fun importProductsInSequence(products: List<Product>): List<Result> =
    products.asSequence()
        .map { saveProduct(it)}
        .takeWhile { products.isNotEmpty() }
        .toList()
```

Is there a possibility to rewrite this sequence so it works in batches? In example, a list of 1000 products is passed to this method, and the sequence is taking 100 products, saves them, then next 100 until `products.isNotEmpty()` condition is met?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`takeWhile` is not needed here, as the `products` list size doesn't change even after you iterate over the sequence. `products.isNotEmpty()` will always be true

Kotlin has `chunked` method that can give you objects in batches as required

```
private fun importProductsInSequence(products: List<Product>): List<Result> =
    products.asSequence()
        .chunked(100)
        .map { saveProducts(it)}  // saveProducts method would take list of products and return list of Result
        .flatten()
        .toList()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I had to rewrite it to map the chunks:   `products.asSequence().chunked(100).map { productChunk -> productChunk.map { saveProduct(it)} }.flatten().toList()`

Comment: ok, in that case, @Nikola's answer would be simpler. if you need to `map` again to save it individually, then chunking might not be required in first place.

Comment: yes. I forgot to approve the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You neeed to use `chunked`

```kotlin
 private fun importProductsInSequence(products: List<Product>): List<Product>{
            products.asSequence().chunked(100).onEach{ saveProduct(it)}.flatten().toList()
```

`chunk` will partition the list to the size provided, the last portion will have less elements than previous one.

Comment: See my comment in @sidgate's answer. I had to rewrite it to map the chunks:   `products.asSequence().chunked(100).map { productChunk -> productChunk.map { saveProduct(it)} }.flatten().toList()`

Comment: You might want to consider batch saving.